# Using schwa in math mode

Tags: automata

I am working on an automata and am trying to use \textschwa or just \schwa in math mode and all I end up getting is an ampersand.  Anyone know how to achieve this in math mode?  the code I am using is below, and the area I would like to place the schwa is in the matrix in edge (7).  Thank you.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state] (0) {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (1) [below right=of 0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (2) [below left=of 1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state] (3) [below right=of 2] {$q_3$};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 3] {$q_4$};
   \node[state] (5) [above right of=4] {$q_5$};
   \node[state] (6) [below right of=5] {$q_6$};
   \node[state] (7) [below left of=6] {$q_7$};
   \path[->]
    (0) edge     node {\textschwa:R} (1)
    (0) edge [loop above]   node {B:\textschwa} (0)
    (1) edge     node {\textschwa:R} (2)
    (1) edge [loop left]   node {B:\textschwa} (1)
    (2) edge    node {B:0:$R_2$} (3)
    (3) edge    node {B:0:$L_2$} (4)
    (4) edge [loop above] node{1:R} (4)
    (4) edge node {0:0} (5)
    (5) edge    [loop above] node{$\begin{matrix}0:$R_2$\\1:$R_2$\end{matrix}$}  (5)
    (5) edge [bend left] node{B:1:L} (6)
    (6) edge [loop right] node{B:$L_2$} (6)
    (6) edge [bend left] node{$x$:E:R} (5)
    (6) edge node{\textschwa:R} (7)
    (7) edge [loop below] node{$\begin{matrix}0:$R_2$\\1:$R_2$\\x:$R_2$\\ {\textschwa}:$R_2$\end{matrix}$} (7)
    (7) edge node{B:0:$L_2$} (4)
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math font switching is a different mechanism than text font switching, as well as symbols being managed differently as well. `\textschwa` refers to the character ə as being character 64 (`@`) in the ipa font which is why you're getting the unexpected character. The simplest route to get your result is to temporarily switch out of math mode to use the `\textschwa` e.g., `\mbox{\textschwa}`. The alternative would be to take the harder route of defining a new math alphabet and declaring a command `\mathschwa` to allow the use of ə in math mode directly, but TeX's limitations on the number of math alphabets allowed makes this a less appealing option.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but in the future, please include a MWE that compiles.  I had to take my best guess what you meant here.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can define `\textschwa` to use the Unicode character ə (U+0259).  In PDFTeX, `\textschwa` is defined in the `tipa` package.

If your font does not support the character, an alternative is `\rotatebox{180}{e}`, from the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \usepackage{newcomputermodern}
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\textschwa}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"0259}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{tipa}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
\fi

\newcommand\mathschwa{\mathalpha{\textnormal{\textschwa}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state] (0) {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (1) [below right=of 0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (2) [below left=of 1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state] (3) [below right=of 2] {$q_3$};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 3] {$q_4$};
   \node[state] (5) [above right of=4] {$q_5$};
   \node[state] (6) [below right of=5] {$q_6$};
   \node[state] (7) [below left of=6] {$q_7$};
   \path[->]
    (0) edge     node {\textschwa:R} (1)
    (0) edge [loop above]   node {B:\textschwa} (0)
    (1) edge     node {\textschwa:R} (2)
    (1) edge [loop left]   node {B:\textschwa} (1)
    (2) edge    node {B:0:$R_2$} (3)
    (3) edge    node {B:0:$L_2$} (4)
    (4) edge [loop above] node{1:R} (4)
    (4) edge node {0:0} (5)
    (5) edge    [loop above] node{\(\begin{matrix}0:R_2 \\ 1: R_2 \end{matrix}\)}  (5)
    (5) edge [bend left] node{B:1:L} (6)
    (6) edge [loop right] node{B:$L_2$} (6)
    (6) edge [bend left] node{$x$:E:R} (5)
    (6) edge node{\textschwa:R} (7)
    (7) edge [loop below] node{\(\begin{matrix}0: R_2 \\ 1:R_2 \\ x:R_2 \\ {\textschwa:R_2} \end{matrix}\)} (7)
    (7) edge node{B:0:$L_2$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ sample]

In this example, I didn’t appear to need a math-mode version, but `{\textnormal{\textschwa}}` should work.  If you wanted it italicized, you can try `\textit{\textschwa}` or `\textnormal{\itshape\textschwa}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am sorry, I do not know what an "MWE" is.

Comment: @Hatsuma Ah, sorry! [Minimal Working Example.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: @Hatsuma I’m surprised that code worked for you. You can’t nest `$` delimiters. Was there some TikZ package that enables that syntax?

Comment: I used packages tipa, TikZ, and amsmath.  Everything works great now, so thanks for your help.  I'm pretty new to LateX, incase you can't tell!